# Getting 400 error with Restassured POST whereas POSTman based request giving 200

Tags: rest-assured, rest-assured-jsonpath

Code snippet

```
@Test(priority = 1)
public void apiFacadePOSTLaunchSurvey() {
    endpoints.chooseEndPoint("accounts");
    response = endpoints.postLaunchSurvey(test_survey_Id_in_draft_state,account_id, jwtToken);

    System.out.println("\n DEBUG:: postLaunchSurvey @@@@@@@-->> after POST"+ response.then().log().all());
    LOGGER.error("*** Logger -> apiFacadePOSTLaunchSurvey response Header-> \n\t"+ response.getHeaders());
    LOGGER.error("*** Logger -> apiFacadePOSTLaunchSurvey response Body-> \n\t"+ response.getBody().asString());
    Assert.assertThat(response.statusCode(), is(equalTo(SC_OK)));
}
```

// Post call

```
    public Response postLaunchSurvey( final int survey_ID, final int account_ID, final String jwtToken) {
    httpRequest.header("Authorization", "Bearer " + jwtToken)
            .header("Content-Type", "application/json");
    httpRequest.pathParams("target_group_id", survey_ID);
    httpRequest.pathParams("account_id", account_ID);
    return httpRequest.post("/{account_id}/target-groups/{target_group_id}/launch");
}
```

RestAssured response:

> response Body->

400 Bad Request

## 400 Bad Request

[image]

I tried adding below code but there's no affect

```
RestAssuredConfig decodeCharset = config().encoderConfig(encoderConfig().appendDefaultContentCharsetToContentTypeIfUndefined(false));
```

Comment: Not enough info to tell which part is wrong? Suggest compare both request log from RA and postman.